# Merging two rows with same BusinessId to a single row and create additional columns

Tags: sql, hana

Merging `Addresses` based on `AddressType` and generating new columns.

I have a query which returns list of businesses by joining table named `Business` with a table called `Addresses`

- `Addresses` table fields: `(ID, BusId, AddrType, Addr, City, State, Zip)`

  - `AddrType` has values 'P' and 'M' (P for Physical and M for Mailing)
- `Business` table fields: `(ID, BusId, BusName, BusDesc etc)`

My query returns data like this after join:

```
BusId BusName  Type    Addr     City   State    Zip Desc

1       XYZ  Physical 100 St    OKC     OK   74820  test

1       XYZ  Mailing  200 St    Allen   OK   73270  test
```

Instead of the above result, I need something like this:

```
BusId BusName PhyAddr MailAddr PhysCity MailCity PhysZip MailZip PhysSt Mailst Desc

1         XYZ    100 St  200 St    OKC      Allen    74820  73270   OK   Ok  Test
```

My Query is

```
select b.BusinessId as BusinessId, BusinessName,CompanyDescription,
       CASE WHEN AddressType = 'P' THEN 'Physical' ELSE 'Mailing' END as AddressType, 
       AddressLine1,AddressLine2, City, State, Zip 
   from Business b join Addresses A 
     on B.BusinessId = A.BusinessId
```

I tried different sub queries but couldn't find a solution.

All I want is to generate new columns like `PhyAddress`, `MailAddress`, `PhyState`, `MailState` for their respective address types and to store the data.

Note: Apart from `Address` all other fields like `Description`, `BusinessId`, `BusinessName` remain the same.

Comment: Can you add your current SQL statement (already tested)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a (N)VARCHAR(4) column with option "GENERATED ALWAYS AS (left(...))

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're wanting, the logic from your case statement needs to be in your join. You want a join to addresses where address type is physical AND a second join to addresses where the address type is mail. Then you can select all the columns you require in order.

Try this...

```
SELECT  b.BusinessId,
        b.BusinessName,
        b.CompanyDescription AS Desc,
       AP.AddressLine1       AS PhyAddr1,
       AP.AddressLine2       AS PhyAddr2, 
       AP.City               AS PhyCity, 
       AP.State              AS PhyState, 
       AP.Zip                AS PhyZip,
       AM.AddressLine1       AS MailAddr1,
       AM.AddressLine2       AS MailAddr2, 
       AM.City               AS MailCity, 
       AM.State              AS MailState, 
       AM.Zip                AS MailZip
  FROM Business b 
  JOIN Addresses AP ON B.BusinessId = AP.BusinessId AND AP.AddrType = 'P'
  JOIN Addresses AM ON B.BusinessId = AM.BusinessId AND AM.AddrType = 'M'
```